# Retrofit/Gson adds \n to large string

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I am using retrofit to to send data as json to my server.

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
```

Everything works fine, but when i try to send a large string (base64 encoded picture) inside of a class, the json converter adds multiple "\n" to the string.

picture":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA...QEBAQEBAQEBAQEB **\n** AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB **\n** A...

This is how send the request:

```
@POST("testservice")
fun test(@Body testBody: TestBody): Call<TestResponse>
```

Call:

```
testService.test(testBody).enqueue(...)
```

Does anyone have a solution to the problem?

The service works perfectly if I don't send the picture.

Comment: how are you sending the request ?

Comment: I´ve added some code

Comment: are you sure that is the json converter doing? from my experience the converter to base64 adds the newlines

Comment: Hi Daniel, that´s it. the base64 encoder adds the newlines.

Comment: if you are logging it using interceptor it could be just a log message, but if it's from the server you need to check the string before sending it